# Linq expression fails in query parser under bizarre conditions

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I've been unable to figure this error out for some time now and am hoping that someone can provide some insight. First, I'll explain the conditions and next I'll describe the conditions under which the error does/doesn't occur.

I have a web api, it has two endpoints /api/getData1 and /api/getData2

I have a web client that makes requests to /api/getData1
I have another application that makes requests to api/getData2

The web api controllers for getData1 and getData2 both end up making a service call to dataService.getData(DateTime date)

dataService.getData(DateTime date) calls StaticFilterClass.buildFilter(DateTime date)

StaticFilterClass.buildFilter(DateTime date)

```
        AlarmFilter filter = null;

        var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Alarm), "a");
        var fieldRef = Expression.Property(paramExpr, "UtcEnd");
        var binaryExpression = Expression.And(
                    Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(fieldRef, Expression.Constant(earliestEnd.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0)).ToUniversalTime(), typeof(DateTime))),
                    Expression.LessThanOrEqual(fieldRef, Expression.Constant(latestEnd.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59)).ToUniversalTime(), typeof(DateTime))));
        filter = (AlarmFilter)Expression.Lambda(binaryExpression, paramExpr);
```

dataService.getData(DateTime date), after getting the filter

```
dbAlarms = tenantDb.Alarms.Where(completeFilter)?.ToList() ?? dbAlarms;
```

The line above conditionally throws

```
"The query view generated for the EntitySet 'Alarms' is not valid. The query parser threw the following error : The argument type 'Edm.String' is not compatible with the property 'UtcEnd' of formal type 'Edm.DateTime'. Near member access expression, line 3, column 77.."}
```

Now, the conditions under which this line throws an error is what has me puzzled.

When the web api is started, if my web client goes to /api/getData1, there is no error. Subsequent calls from the web client to /api/getData1 succeed **and** subsequent calls from the other application to /api/getData2 succeed.

When the web api is started, if my other application goes to /api/getData2 first, the error above is generated. Subsequent calls from the application to /api/getData2 **and** subsequent calls from the web client to /api/getData1 throw the error above.

Can anyone help to point me in the right direction?

Edit:
It seemed to have something to do with the load order of the database project .dll (referenced by the client app and the api). I moved a couple of db transactions from the client application (where it accessed the db directly) into the web api so that the api would be the first thing to hit the database, and because it made more sense anyway. Still not sure of the root cause, but this resolves the issue.

Comment: is anything here getting stored into, say, a static field?

Comment: The only thing potentially being used in the concerned method might be: using AlarmFilter = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Database.Entities.Alarm, bool>>;

Comment: So, what's the difference between getData1 and getData2?

Comment: One accepts a request object from some application and returns a pdf, the other from a web client and returns json or a pdf. In both cases, a call is made to dataService.getDate(DateTime date)

Comment: Can you debug it and compare results of buildFilter in both cases?

Comment: What version of EF?

Comment: They match exactly and both look like this:  ".Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Entities.Alarm,System.Boolean]>(Entities.Alarm $a)\r\n{\r\n    $a.UtcEnd >= .Constant<System.DateTime>(8/1/2018 12:00:00 AM) & $a.UtcEnd <= .Constant<System.DateTime>(8/5/2018 11:59:00 PM)\r\n}"

Comment: EF 6.2.0, I updated from an earlier version in an attempt to fix this

Answer (score 0):

I can think only 2 think:
1) You need to specify a where return object like below:

```
bAlarms = tenantDb.Alarms.Where<MyReturnObject>(completeFilter)?.ToList<MyReturnObject>() ?? dbAlarms;
```

2) Inside "alarms" there is a static class/function that will be accessed at the same time by getData1 and Getdata2.